# Get rid of an extra empty space on the right side of the navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

a newb here looking to solve a css problem with my navigation bar.

There is an extra empty space on the right side that should not be there. I would like the li elements to fill the nav bar completely with all properties intact.

Can you please help and see what in my css code is the culprit?

Thank you

```css
#nav {
 

      height: 46px;
}

#nav > li {
 float: left;
 
 padding: 14px 29px 10px 29px;
 
 border-right:1px solid #eae5e4;
 border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
}
#nav > li a {
 color: #7d8184;
 font-size: 15px;
}
#nav > li:last-child { border-right:none; }
#nav > li.over, #nav > li:hover, #nav > li.active {
 
 border-bottom:5px solid #f15a3b;
}
#nav > li > a > span {
 
}
#nav > li.over.parent {
}
#nav .homelink {
 
}
#nav .custommenuitem {
 border-left:1px solid #eae5e4;
 border-right:none;
 display:none;
}

#nav li.block_li > a > span, #nav li.block_li > a {
 cursor: default;
}
#nav li div.custom_menu_item {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 15px;
 z-index: 1500;
 width: 980px;
 margin-left: -1px;
 border: 1px solid #EAE5E4;
 top:45px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML as well. The CSS alone doesn't really mean anything without the HTML and as you can see, nothing shows up when you run the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

divide 100% by the number of drop downs you have then insert that width pecentage here like this

```
#nav > li {
float: left;
width: 25%; /* if you had 4 dropdowns*/
padding: 14px 29px 10px 29px;

border-right:1px solid #eae5e4;
border-left:1px solid #ffffff;}
```

Comment: I did a temporary fix by adding a few pixels to the right and left padding :/ for the most part, it did the trick...